# Creating MatPlotLib diverging colormap with a single color

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, customization, colormap

How can I create a custom diverging colormap in matplotlib such that it would use a single color (i.e. the same color on the vmin and vmax ends, and white in the middle)?

All of the default ones use 2 different colors:

[https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html](http://Matplotlib%20colormaps)

I need to show cases where some value deviates from its mean and it is more important to show the magnitude of the deviation and not the direction (direction will the shown through cell annotations).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I guess you mean `matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["red", "white", "red"])`?

Comment: This is perfect - exactly what is need. If you make it an answer, I will accept it :)

Comment: I don't think there needs to be an answer for each combination of colors.